# CoreBluetooth - Enviar e receber um pacote grande de dados

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para iOS utilizando apenas CoreBluetooth, na mesma aplicação o dispositivo poderá ser um Central ou um Peripheral.
Pois bem, tudo funciona tudo certo, até que tento enviar um pacote de dados acima do limite permitido pelo "slave"(dispositivo periférico que comanda o limite de dados que podem trafegados a cada requisição do central).

Possuo 3 characteristic:

```
    CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
    CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
    CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
```

Consigo enviar um pacote muito grande do periférico para o central utilizando a forma indicada pela Apple no app BTLE_Transfer (CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify), porém, preciso que os seguintes métodos enviem um pacote de dados maior que o estipulado:

```
    - (void)writeValue:(NSData *)data forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic type:(CBCharacteristicWriteType)type;
    - (void)readValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;
```

Quando chamo estes métodos com um pacote de bytes pequeno, tudo acontece normalmente, mas quando este pacote aumenta, ele sempre retorna no delegate responsável pela resposta de cada método, um pacote de 628 bytes (menor que o pacote que foi enviado pelo outro lado).
Se envio acima de 628 bytes, sempre é retornado 628 bytes, não sendo possível deserializar o data do outro lado (peripheral ou central).

Alguém sabe por quê isto acontece? Percebi que quando envio um pacote de 2000 bytes por exemplo, o delegate responsável pelo readValueForCharacteristic é chamado 4 vezes, porém, não consigo montar o pacote corretamente. Alguém teria uma explicação?

Comment: Já levou em consideração em utilizar o GameKit que tem o suporte completo pra comunicação via Bluetooth.

Comment: Não. Sabe se o Peer se comunica com Android? Segui a linha de desenvolver em cima do CoreBluetooth pois meu aplicativo final precisa se comunicar com um app Android similar, e desta forma eu consegui esta comunicação.

Comment: Eu achava que o Bump fazia isso que vc quer fazer porem ele usa a internet para transferir do ios pro android. http://canaltech.com.br/dica/mobile/bump-basta-bater-para-transfirerir-arquivos-entre-iphone-android-e-pc/